# How can I do pixel-wise computation with a xf:Mat?

Tags: vivado-hls

I am trying to migrating my opencv code to Xilinx xfopencv. I want to do pixel wise division of two input images.c(x,y)=a(x,y)/b(x,y)

How can I get c by using xfOpenCv???
In OpenCv, I can directly do a/b, but xfOpenCv do not have pixel-wize division function. I tried to define a division function by myself.

but I got error: '[]' could not be resolved
So how can I do pixel-wise computation with a xf:Mat ?
Could you give an example?

```
error: '[]' could not be resolved

xf::Mat<XF_8UC1, HEIGHT, WIDTH, XF_NPPC1> a;
xf::Mat<XF_8UC1, HEIGHT, WIDTH, XF_NPPC1> b;
xf::Mat<XF_8UC1, HEIGHT, WIDTH, XF_NPPC1> c;

for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
   {
      c[i][j] = a[i][j]/b[i][j];
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

use the '.data' pointer to access each pixel value of an xf::Mat object.

```
for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++){
 for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++){
      c.data[i*WIDTH+j] = a.data[i*WIDTH+j] / b.data[i*WIDTH+j];
}
```

}